# Why can I not generalize O(n^log5) for squaring matrice of size n

Tags: matrices, algorithms, asymptotics, recursive-algorithms

I have a question that is bugging me for around a 3 days, I first asked this question in stackoverflow but no one could answer it reasonably though they tried to help, so finally I found here as a last chance for help:

As you know multiplying 2 matrice is basically 6 subproblems and I made it 5 by the following manipulation,

[image]

so we can say that squaring matrice of 2*2 is O(n^log5)
now my problem starts : I am trying to come up with two reasons that this can not be generalized for n*n, I wrote these reasonings in the exam and I got nothing for themso I understood that these are not correct :

1) If we multiply A*A (4*4) we will see that we get at lest 6 distinct multiplication and so T(n) >=6T(n/2)+n^2 and O is at least n^log6 which is n^epsolon greater than n^log5 so n^log6 is asymptotically slower

2) For multiplication of A*A when n=2 we have 5 multiplication and for n>2 we can say that at least 1 multiplication is added to the number of multiplication that we had for n=2 because at least one row and one column are added to our matrix which affects the # of multiplication so we can say that we foe n>2 we have at least 6 multiplication and it is enough for concluding that for n>2 we may get slower running time so we can not generalize n^log5

So  I was suggested to look at it in this way: I should find things that I am doing in squaring a 2x2 that stop it from turning into a recursive step for square arrays. But the problem is that I am stuck and cannot go any further. what are does things that stop stop aquaring 2*2 matrice from turning into a recursive step for square arrays?

Thanks for your answer beforehand.:)

Comment: For every *fixed* $n$ the runtime is obviously $\mathcal O(1)$. I don't understand how you get the $\mathcal O\left(n^{\log 5}\right)$? Furthermore $\log$ to which base do you mean here? (thats essential here!) Btw, afaik the fastest known algorithm for matrix multiplication is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm which has runtime $\mathcal O\left( n^{2.3727} \right)$ what's  acutal *slower* than $\mathcal O\left( n^{\log_2 5} \right)$

Comment: The trick itself can be applied to matrices bigger than $2\times 2$ without any problems... but it will *not* help you get the desired time complexity of $O(n^{\log_2 5})$. This is because it reduces the problem of *squaring* one matrix of size $n$ into five sub-problems... of *matrix multiplication*, only *two* of which are squarings! The corresponding recurrence would look like $T(n)=2T(n/2)+3M(n/2)+O(n^2)$, with $M(n)$ being time complexity of matrix multiplication which we don't know how to do fast enough to fit into $O(n^{\log_2 5})$ yet.

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 Thanks for answering, Yes I will correct it the question is to explain 2 reasons that generalization to O(n^log5)(base 2) is not possible?(by the way base is 2)

Comment: @PeterKošinár Thanks for answering but still it is  a little fuggy when we say 5 subproblem it mease that we have 5 recurrence so what is the difference between squaring and not squaring elements?